# how to print "return" value from function?

Tags: php, json

I need simple clarification for this.
This is my function.
How can I echo "return" value, I want to get that "return" value to variable.
please help me to do this.

```
function get_mail_conformation($conf_code) {
    $data = file_get_contents('https://api.elasticemail.com/mailer/status/' . $conf_code . '?showstats=true');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    if (isset($array['delivered'])) {
        if ($array['delivered'] == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (isset($array['pending'])) {
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (isset($array['pending'])) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `echo get_mail_conformation(...);`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//paste your code here
//function get_mail_conformation($conf_code) {
//  
//}

$confcode = "somecode1234";
echo get_mail_conformation($confcode);
?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Inside php tags with scope to your function

```
$conf_code = 'put your conf here';
$confirmation = get_mail_conformation($conf_code);
echo $confirmation;
```

For your echo you can also put it into a more palatable human readable form with something like

```
$potential_confirmations = array('failed', 'delivered', 'pending');
echo $potential_confirmations[$confirmation];
```

Hope this gives you what you need.